# JavaScript validate existence of date

Tags: javascript, validation, date

I have a date in the format YYMMDD. Is there anyway I can validate it in JavaScript?
By validation I don't mean easier things like length, characters etc but rather if the date exists in real life.

I'm hoping there is a faster / better way than breaking it in 3 chunks of 2 characters and checking each individually.

Thank you.

Comment: 000229 is valid for 2000, but invalid for 1900. So you need to think about the range of your dates (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year#Algorithm)

Answer (score 3):

try to convert it to a date and if it fails, you get the dreaded `NaN` then you know it is not a valid date string? Not Pretty but it should work

```
var myDate = new Date(dateString);
// should write out NaN
document.write("Date : " + myDate);
```

[You date string would have to be in a valid format for javascript](http://programming.top54u.com/Samples/Javascript/Date-Object/Convert-String-to-Date/Default.aspx) I don't think what you have in your question `YYMMDD` is supported

Comment: That's a good idea and beats validating each chunk. I can get the missing YY to make it an YYYYMMDD format. I'll give it a go and let you know. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The format YYMMDD is not supported by Javascript Date.parse so you have to do some processing of it like breaking it in parts.

I would suggest building a function that splits it in 3 2 char strings and then builds an american style date

MM/DD/YY and try to parse that with Date.parse.

If it returns anything but NaN then its a valid date.

Answer (score 1):

The `Date` parser in JavaScript is pretty useless. The actual formats it accepts vary greatly across browsers; the only formats guaranteed to work by the ECMAScript standard are whatever formats the implementation's `toString` and `toUTCString` methods produce. In ECMAScript Fifth Edition you will also get ISO-8166 format, which is nearer to your format but still not quite.

So, the best solution is usually to parse it yourself.

```
var y= parseInt(s.slice(0, 2), 10)+2000;
var m= parseInt(s.slice(2, 4), 10)-1;
var d= parseInt(s.slice(4, 6), 10);
var date= new Date(Date.UTC(y, m, d));
```

Now you've got a `Date` object representing the input date in UTC. But that's not enough, because the `Date` constructor allows bogus months like 13 or days like 40, wrapping around. So to check the given day was a real day, convert back to year/month/day and compare:

```
var valid= date.getUTCFullYear()===y && d.getUTCMonth()===m && d.getUTCDate()===d;
```